timezone conversion from tibble dataframe
I'm downloading a tibble dataframe from the alphavantager R package.  I'm trying to convert the timestamp column from the default Eastern timezone to UTC.  All of my attempts leave the timestamp unchanged, except for putting the suffix "UTC" at the end in some of the attempts.
library('alphavantager')

tst <- av_get(symbol         = "NKE",
              av_fun         = "TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY",
              interval       = "15min",
              extended_hours = "false",
              month          = "2024-03",
              outputsize     = "full") 

# parsing out 1 day  
tst<-tst[as.Date(tst$timestamp)=='2024-03-01',]

# attempt #1
tst$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(as.integer(tst$timestamp),tz="UTC")

# attempt #2
tst$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(as.integer(tst$timestamp), origin="1970-01-01", tz="UTC")

# attempt #3
tst<-as.data.frame(tst)

tst$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(as.integer(tst$timestamp),tz="UTC")

# attempt #4
tst <- as.list(tst)

tst$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(as.integer(tst$timestamp),tz="UTC")`

# example data
dput(head(tst$timestamp))

# Output of dput
# structure(c(1709285400, 1709286300, 1709287200, 1709288100, 
# 1709289000,1709289900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = 
#"UTC")



Try df <- data.frame(timestamp = as.POSIXct("2024-04-24 11:00", tz = "America/New_York"));   df$ts_UTC = lubridate::with_tz(df$timestamp, "UTC");   df. See https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/with_tz.html

no dice with the following:  df$ts_UTC = lubridate::with_tz(df$timestamp, "UTC")

as.integer looks odd to me. as.POSIXct works fine with class(character), e.g. as.POSIXct("2024-03-01", tz="UTC")

Can you share some example data by running dput(head(tst$timestamp)) and pasting the output into the body of your question?

"No dice" as it doesn't run, or it does run but the output is wrong?

@ Jon Spring:  Apologies for not providing additional detail.  It runs, but the date stays the same, which is what happens in all of my "attempts".   I've been able to run the timezone conversion successfully on other dataframes without issue.  I think what might be happening is when the data is pulled from alpha advantage it's pulling it into a tibble dataframe which isn't allowing any of the timezone conversions to take place

I added the dput(head(tst$timestamp)) to the body of my question.  The structure looks like it's showing as "UTC" but I've attached a screen grab that shows the output is still showing as EST

@Andre Wildberg:  Yes, I'm able to get that logic to work with just a hard coded date, but for some reason it's not working with my tibble dataframe.  You can download the same dataframe but you have to grab a free api code from alpha advantage.  takes about 5 seconds, but that would be the fastest way to recreate the dataframe I'm working from

It downloads as tz = UTC for me and I can change it to CET. (The source Alphavantager JSON metadata shows EST.)
You could set the tz to EST as that's what the downloaded time actually reflects, then use with_tz(timestamp, tzone = "UTC") to shift the hours.
library(alphavantager)
library(lubridate)

av_api_key("xxx")

tst <- av_get(
  symbol = "NKE",
  av_fun = "TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY",
  interval = "15min",
  extended_hours = "false",
  month = "2024-03",
  outputsize = "full"
)

# Downloaded as UTC
tz(tst$timestamp)
#> [1] "UTC"
tst$timestamp[1]
#> [1] "2024-03-01 09:30:00 UTC"

# Change to CET
tz(tst$timestamp) <- "CET"
tz(tst$timestamp)
#> [1] "CET"
tst$timestamp[1]
#> [1] "2024-03-01 09:30:00 CET"

# Equivalent to
x <- as_datetime("2024-03-01 09:30:00")
x
#> [1] "2024-03-01 09:30:00 UTC"
tz(x) <- "CET"
x
#> [1] "2024-03-01 09:30:00 CET"


# To adjust the actual time
library(dplyr)

tz(tst$timestamp) <- "EST"
tst$timestamp[1]
#> [1] "2024-03-01 09:30:00 EST"

tst2 <- tst |> mutate(timestamp = with_tz(timestamp, tzone = "UTC"))
tst2$timestamp[1]
#> [1] "2024-03-01 14:30:00 UTC"

# Metadata
#> [1] https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&outputsize=full&apikey=demo


Created on 2024-04-25 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks for the solution Carl.  The EST display time even though it was UTC was throwing me off.  Changing it to EST and then converting back to UTC solved the problem and it is now displaying as intended.
